# Issue with Installing PyObjC for Python

Tags: python, pyobjc

I was attempting to install PyObjC on my Mac OS X El Capitan, and about 40 minutes into the download, I received an error and it stopped. I tried installing using the following code in my terminal:

```
pip install pyobjc
```

The error says:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
/private/var/folders/6x/pl46qrrj2n51fs9z00cw46240000gn/T/pip_build_Dustin/pyobjc-framework
-AVKit
 Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Dustin/Library/Logs/pip.log
```

I am using Xcode Version 7.3 and have been searching online for some answers but have been unable to find anything that seems to help. Any suggestions as to how to get the download to complete?

Comment: Could you share the log please?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/quXXfANz

Comment: I've also seen elsewhere that some people will downgrade their setup tools version to 19.2 to help with some installations. Would that also be a possibility with pyobjc?

Comment: It may be that the database for the new version screws up the versions. I suggest you try these methods, especially the last one (installing separately) and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Python 2.7, but from the logs, it appears as though you're trying to install `pyobjc` for a different version, most probably Python 3.

> Line 267: pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pyobjc-core 2.5.1
>   (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC),
>   Requirement.parse('pyobjc-core>=3.1.1'))

If you wish to use Python 3, use this method to install:

```
python3 -m pip install pyobj
```

Alternatively, I suggest you go ahead and download `pyobjc` from [here](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/downloads), and install it manually from the source using this command:

- For Python 2.7: `python2.7 pyobjc/install.py`
- For Python 3.x: `python3 pyobjc/install.py`

The documentations [here](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/src) and [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/install.html), clearly explain the installation process in further details. The latter deals with some possible problems, too.

Another alternative is to try `easy_install`:

```
python -m easy_install pyobjc
```

### Note

Please ensure that you have `commandline-tools` from `xcode` installed before attempting to install `pyobjc`. Also, make sure that you run this in your terminal beforehand if you use Mac OS X 10.8 or lower.

```
 xcode-select --install.
```

Finally, it might be a good idea to install the core separately:

```
python2.7 -m pip install -U pyobjc-core
python2.7 -m pip install -U pyobjc
```

Lets try these and see if they work!

Answer (score 1):

Hey please make sure to check that you have installed these dependencies:

```
image==1.5.27
numpy==1.17.4
Pillow==6.2.1
requests==2.22.0
opencv-python
olefile==0.46
PyAutoGUI==0.9.48
PyMsgBox==1.0.7
pyobjc-core==6.2
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==6.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==5.3
PyScreeze==0.1.26
PyScreeze==0.1.26
PyTweening==1.0.3
pathlib
```

Add these to your `requirements.txt` file and install with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

That should solve the problem. Also make sure that you are using python versions 3.6 and above

Answer (score 0):

This error recurred in the Python 3 context.

As of the Big Sur update on October 12, 2021, after trying a lot of other solutions, this fixed it for me:

```
pip install pyobjc-core==8.0b1
pip install pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==8.0b1
pip install pyobjc-framework-Quartz==8.0b1
```