# While installing pyttsx3 over python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, windows, module, pycharm, pyttsx

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\91826\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2vyil_3k\\pyobjc-framework-Cocoa\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\91826\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
pip-install-2vyil_3k\\pyobjc-framework-Cocoa\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\User
s\91826\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2vyil_3k\pyobjc-framework-Cocoa\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\91826\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2vyil_3k\pyobjc-framework-Cocoa\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\91826\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2vyil_3k\pyobjc-framework-Cocoa\setup.py", line 22, in <module>
        Extension(
      File "C:\Users\91826\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2vyil_3k\pyobjc-framework-Cocoa\pyobjc_setup.py", line 408, in Extension
        os_level = get_os_level()
      File "C:\Users\91826\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2vyil_3k\pyobjc-framework-Cocoa\pyobjc_setup.py", line 218, in get_os_level
        pl = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist")
      File "c:\python\lib\plistlib.py", line 99, in readPlist
        with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
      File "c:\python\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "c:\python\lib\plistlib.py", line 82, in _maybe_open
        with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably its a problem on a pyobj installing,

Check if old versions released can solve your problem,
https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/releases

To install pyobj on windows,
i cant help you, because i dont solved this problem: P
But  you can try this way can help you installing by easy_install instead of pip
[Issue with Installing PyObjC for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813269/issue-with-installing-pyobjc-for-python)

Comment: i did it by making my pycharm as a administrator, pyttsx2.7 got installed

Comment: @arbazsheikh Because only last "release" 2.80 need pyobj