# How do I add Foundation module in Python3 on MacOS Ventura?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-ventura

I have a program that runs in python3 and uses the Foundation module, but I recently upgraded to Ventura and I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Applications/Presentation.app/Contents/MacOS/presentation.py", line 162, in <module>
        from Foundation import (
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'
```

I'm sure it's easy to add it, but I have no idea how. Another question ([ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875164/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-foundation)) sounds similar, and suggests to install `pyobjc` - which makes total sense, but I don't seem to be able to do that. After some searching (and updating pip) I get:

```
$ sudo -H python3 -m pip install pyobj
Collecting pyobj
  Using cached pyobj-1.0.tar.gz (767 bytes)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/tmp/pip-install-zz43ztlh/pyobj_a4e8c29f95d8421d909f4f5e29a55190/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          from web import __version__
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'web'
      [end of output]
```

And trying to install `web` doesn't find anything. So I'm guessing this isn't the right way to do this.

I also see posts (including [Issue with Installing PyObjC for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813269/issue-with-installing-pyobjc-for-python)) suggesting to:

```
$ xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" in System Settings to install updates
```

But it is already installed and (I checked) up to date.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875164/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-foundation)

Comment: Sorry, no it doesn't. I've updated my question based on that and other links.